# a[1:-1] vs a[1:len(a)] in Python

Tags: python

I was working on the PygLatin exercise on Codeacademy and one point of the exercise asked you to slice the variable so that it contained everything but the first element. The suggested method was to use `a = a[1:len(a)]`, I however tried to use `a = a[1:-1]`, but it failed. It went to the second last element but not the last (eg for the input `justin`, it outputted `ustinja` instead of `ustinjay`). As I understand it `-1` represents the last element in the list, so I was wondering why this method did not work.

Here is the code I wrote:

```
    pyg = 'ay'

    original = raw_input('Enter a word:')

    if len(original) > 0 and original.isalpha():
        word = original.lower()
        first = word[0]
        new_word = word + first + pyg
        # new_word = new_word[1:-1] # this line did not work
        new_word = new_word[1:len(new_word)] # this line did work
    else:
         print 'empty'
```

Comment: I don't know the difference, but you can use `word[1:]` and get the same effect.

Comment: `-1` indeed represents the last element, but when you define a range/slice it excludes the last element, meaning: `a[1:2]` will contain only one element: `a[1]`.

Comment: In python the indexing starts from `0`. This means that `a[1:-1]` will take from the second element til `-1`, which is not the last but the second to last. if you want to take till the last you will either need to specify it by using `a[1:len(a)]`or as suggested by the comments above use `a[1:]` and leave it blank.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As [documented](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange), a slice `[x:y]` includes the element at index `x` but not at `y`.  So `[1:-1]` is everything from (and including) the second element, up to (but not including) the last element.

The reason `[1:len(a)]` works is that `len(a)` is bigger than the biggest index, because indices are numbered starting with 0.  For instance, the string `"justin"` has length 6 but its last character is at index 5.  A slice that goes "past the end" is considered to stop at the end, so `[1:len(a)]` works for the same reason `[1:1000000]` would work; as long as the second part of the slice is bigger than the last index, it will go all the way to the end.

However, if you want everything but the first character, you don't need a second part to the slice at all.  Just do `new_word[1:]`.